# What's the different between <!DOCTYPE> and <!doctype html>(CSS set inner block height by percentage and containing block to auto , something wrong)

Tags: html, css

According to specific  [Content height: the 'height' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height) pecentages

> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the
>   height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it
>   depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely
>   positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

I write this:

```
<body>
        <div style="height:auto;">
            <div style="height: 100%;background-color: blue;"></div>
        </div>
</body>
```

I think the inner div's height must be 0.

But the truth is that the height equals to the body's height . (The whole screen is blue)

Why's that?

test in :
Chrome 34. IE 10 FF 28

### **Found the problem !**

in my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
```

and the right way is :

```
<!doctype html>
```

now I wonder what's different?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so http://jsfiddle.net/2n2kx/

Comment: Ditto: (http://jsfiddle.net/99p9c/1/)

Comment: Since there is absolutely no content in the HTML you have given, then the body's height should be zero, making *both* of your statements true (the body's height is zero, the outer div's height is auto, and the inner div's height computes to auto, so all of their used heights are zero). What exactly do you see and what browser are you testing in?

Comment: @Joey *now I wonder what's different?* - **IT's A WRONG DOCTYPE**

Answer (score 0):

The inner div's height *is* 0 - because

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

So your inner div's 100%, is being computed as 'auto' - and since there is no content to 'auto' size the div to, it gets 0, just like it's parent.

See the different between these two JSFiddles:

Setting `height:auto` (like you have it): http://jsfiddle.net/9gZw8/

explicitly set the height of the outer div `height: 100px` (now it does fill 100% of the parent): http://jsfiddle.net/gE7ea/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<style>
  html, body, .box{
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  .div1{
    height:40%;
    background-color:#666;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="div1">TEST</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening here and how it addresses the question at hand? Just dropping a block of code and saying "Try this" isn't very helpful.

Comment: It seems to be correct. But can you explain this in brief.